# MySQL Triggers using phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to write a very simple trigger for MySQL using phpmyadmin 4.0.8,
what I want to do, is after a table called 'upload' is inserted into, I take  the username, and id and put it into a second table called 'rating'

This is what I'm trying,

CREATE TRIGGER copy_pid AFTER INSERT on upload FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO rating (uid,pid) VALUES (NEW.username,NEW.id);

END;

I get an "#1064 - You have an error in..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is interpreting the semi-colon at the end of your INSERT statement as the end of the input. You need to change your delimiter while youe set up your trigger:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER copy_pid AFTER INSERT on upload FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN

INSERT INTO rating (uid,pid) VALUES (NEW.username,NEW.id);

END$$
delimiter ;
```

Comment: That does fix it! But... now when I insert into upload nothing ends up in the table

Comment: This is what I'm doing now
"DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS copy_pid //

CREATE TRIGGER copy_pid AFTER INSERT on sc_main.upload FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

INSERT INTO sc_main.rating (uid, pid) VALUES (NEW.username, NEW.id);

END"

Comment: I didn't look at what your trigger was actually doing. Does your new code do what you need?

Comment: no, it just stops my from inserting into the table the this triggers on. But it did answer my syntax error I was wondering about